# ColdFusion - Variable DSNNAME is undefined

Tags: php, apache, coldfusion

I'm maintain a customer website - **PHP** - and today, when I migrate from a shared server to a VPS... I need to configure **coldfusion** from scratch.

*Obs.: I never use ColdFusion in my life*

But I get this error: **Variable DSNNAME is undefined**. And I don't where I configure that.

```
The web site you are accessing has experienced an unexpected error.
Please contact the website administrator. 

The following information is meant for the website developer for debugging purposes.
Error Occurred While Processing Request
Variable DSNNAME is undefined.


The error occurred in /home/project/public_html/projectname/integracao/register/members_body.cfm: line 303
Called from /home/project/public_html/projectname/integracao/register/frame.cfm: line 45
Called from /home/project/public_html/projectname/integracao/register/members.cfm: line 5
301 :         <td>
302 :           <div align="right">
303 :             <cfquery name="Qry_location" datasource="#dsnname#">
304 :               SELECT * FROM location      
305 :               WHERE location_active = '1' 
Resources:
Check the ColdFusion documentation to verify that you are using the correct syntax.
Search the Knowledge Base to find a solution to your problem.
Browser   Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/38.0.2125.104 Safari/537.36
Remote Address    189.15.195.13
Referrer    http://projectname/site/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=53&Itemid=12
Date/Time   27-Oct-14 07:17 PM
Stack Trace
at cfmembers_body2ecfm207100474.runPage(/home/project/public_html/projectname/integracao/register/members_body.cfm:303) at cfframe2ecfm1139106636.runPage(/home/project/public_html/projectname/integracao/register/frame.cfm:45) at cfmembers2ecfm1994964255.runPage(/home/project/public_html/projectname/integracao/register/members.cfm:5) 

coldfusion.runtime.UndefinedVariableException: Variable DSNNAME is undefined.
  at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._get(CfJspPage.java:388)
  at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._get(CfJspPage.java:350)
```

---

My structure is that:

```
/home/project/public_html/projectname/application.cfm
/home/project/public_html/projectname/integracao/register/members_body.cfm
```

**I need that members.cfm file, read the file Application.cfm**. How can I do that?

Comment: Step 1 - Look to where you think you defined the variable.  It's got nothing to do with an actual datasource.

Comment: Thats the problem my friend: I never use ColdFusion in my life. It's the first time. I don't know where is defined.

Comment: You might be over your head, but you have to find it.  Use whatever tools you have at your disposal to look for the string "dsnname".  If you don't see it being assigned a value anywhere, that's why it's undefined.  If you do, you have to follow the code and see why it's not defined in that query tag.

Comment: check Appliaction.cfc (or .cfm for older apps) since constants are usually set there.

Comment: The datasource could also be defined in the ColdFusion administrator. You can use the ColdFusion Archive section of the administrator to save your old server's configuration (if that server still exists) and then import those settings to your new server. [Packaging applications in CAR files](http://help.adobe.com/livedocs/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=deploying_3.html)

Comment: Do a text search on the site for either `<cfset dsnname="` or `<cfset variables.dsnname=` .  Like @Henry said, I would guess that it is in either `application.cfc` or `application.cfm`

Comment: my best guess is that the variable is set in the `application.cfm` and that the `application.cfm` wasn't copied to the new server. it might have been outside/above the webroot

Comment: @DanBracuk I found that the `application.cfc` but I don't know why my `cfm` files not read that file.

Comment: @Henry I found that the `application.cfc` but I don't know why my `cfm` files not read that file.

Comment: In the ColdFusion admin, in the debug option, set the debug options so that it shows the stack trace.

Comment: @JamesAMohler I'll do that now, but I not found the configuration for set the location of my `application.cfm`

Comment: Nothing to do with your question, but as soon you get this issue resolved, I would strongly recommend reviewing the [CF LockDown/Security Guides](http://www.carehart.org/blog/client/index.cfm/2014/6/24/ColdFusion_Lockdown_Security_guides). The Admin url should not be public.

Comment: There is no configuration that sets `application.cfc` It is just automatically based on what page is being requested. For example If you are requesting a page in `d:\sites\mysite\index.cfm`, ColdFusion will look for `d:\sites\mysite\application.cfc` Nothing is explicitly done to run this file.

Comment: You may want to review: http://www.learncfinaweek.com/week1/Application_cfc/

Comment: @JamesAMohler But I have just `application.cfm`, not `cfc`. And... in the entire application I have just one file.

Comment: @PatrickMaciel did the application.cfc file set that variable anywhere?  If so, was in set within a function?  If so, what function?

Comment: @DanBracuk I not have the `application.cfc` file... just `cfm`. In `application.cfm` I have the **application.dsnname** set.

Comment: @PatrickMaciel CF would seek `application.cfc` or `.cfm` from where `members_body.cfm` is to the root.  If you have an `application.cfc` or `.cfm` in, say `/integracao` folder, then CF will use that one and that one only.

Comment: @Henry right, but: why in the old shared server, this CF application have only 1 `application.cfm` in `public_html` folder?

Comment: @PatrickMaciel I don't know, but it seems like you just need to determine what application.cfm it is now using for `members_body.cfm` then make sure the `DSNNAME` value is set.

Comment: @Henry my problem is: who to define to every `cfm` file read the `/application.cfm`. Anyway, I solved it another way: including manually the '/application.cfm` in every file. Crazy right?

Comment: @PatrickMaciel yes, pretty crazy.  CF should automatically resolve to call application.cfm, unless there were an application.cfm that lives closer relative to your calling page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `<cfinclude template="/application.cfm"/>`

Are you on *nix? If so, [application file names are case sensitive](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7d6f.html). Is your file named `Application.cfm`? Note the first letter is upper case "A". If not, that could explain why it does not fire. CF is looking for `Application.cfm`, not `application.cfm`. So the latter would be ignored.

Comment: Glad I could help :) Don't forget to review the [security guides](http://www.carehart.org/blog/client/index.cfm/2014/6/24/ColdFusion_Lockdown_Security_guides). It is very important you restrict access to the Admin url.

Answer (score 1):

Like you said, you have to configure it from scratch. If you never worked with CF before, afew points.

1. To run your queries in CF code you need to connect them with a database. That is done through Datasource Attribute of CFQUERY.
2. As a general practice, developers often store the darasource name in a persistent variable and keep it inside Application.cfm or Application.cfc. In your case this persistent variable's name is DSNNAME.
3. ColdFusion needs to establish a connection with the database. That is done by creating a connection in the CF Admin screen, through the link you posted.

That said, this is how you do it: Say you have a SQL Server database, click on Data Sources and add the Data Source from there. Pretty easy it is. Once you create the Data Source, assign that Datasource to the `DSNNAME` variable in Application.cfm or Application.cfc.

Comment: Ok... I think my CFM files can not read `application.cfm`. Where I find this configuration?

Comment: I just saw your comment, you have Application.cfc file. Search for that file for the variable name DSNNAME

Comment: As you have migrated the application from shared to VPS, did you configured the DSN in CF Admin yet?

Comment: @PatrickMaciel: Is there an `application.cfm` or an `application.cfc` ?

Answer (score 0):

Somehow, a ColdFusion config file needed by your application is not being read properly. It might not have been included in the .cfm files you were given, as this sort of file is often server-specific and put on source code management ignore lists.

If the file exists, but is not being called, you can probably find it by searching for strings like `dsnname=` `dsnname =` etc.

What you pasted into your question is the CF Administrator console, which probably won't help fix this issue. You will however have to make sure the database is properly configured and named to match whatever #dsnname# evaluates to.

Your best bet might be to contact whomever wrote the code and ask if a config/settings file might have been left out.

Answer (score 0):

I solve that problem including the `application.cfm` in every page.

Yes, it's crazy, but is the only solution works.

```
<cfinclude template="/application.cfm"/>
```

But what I wanted is every `.cfm` file **auto-include** `application.cfm`, as the old shared hosting.

Comment: Hm... are you on *nix? If so, the [application file names are case sensitive](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7d6f.html). Is your file named `Application.cfm`? Note the first letter is upper case "A"

Comment: If not, that could explain why it does not fire. CF is looking for a file named "Application.cfm" not "application.cfm". So the latter is ignored.

Comment: @Leigh my file is `application.cfm` not 'Application.cfm`. I'll try rename to `Application.cfm`...

Comment: @Leigh You right my friend! Thanks! Please, add another answer for me.